# How can I get a variable from the path in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-v4

My react router works fine.. but I would like get the date from the `Path` as the `title` which expects a string.

```
  <Route exact path="/meeting/:date"
              breadcrumb="Meetings"
              title={DATE}
              component={(props) => (
                <FooComponent
                  date={props.match.params.date} />
              )}
            />
```

thanks

Comment: If you use v4, As I daw in docs,  the only place where you can extract url params is in the wrapped component, such as you used in FooComponent. Can you share the purpose of title as Route prop? maybe you should replace your title logic to somewhere else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your initial component, set the path that loads your route.  By adding /:date to the end of your route, that string can be accessed by calling props.match.params.date inside that routes component.

`<Route exact path="/meeting/:date" component={DateComponent} />`

In the component that the route renders, use `props.match.params.date` to access your string from path

```
Class DateComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <h2>{this.props.match.params.date}</h2>
    )
  }
}
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match

Comment: This solution is for React-router v4, if you're using version 5, please refer to Ishan Mujdeci's answer below

Answer (score 34):

There is a new api in `react-router-dom 5.1`

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

function MyComponent(){
    const {date} = useParams()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) for that, it allows you to update the title, meta, scripts and basically anything related to the header.

Once you install it, just add the following code to `FooComponent` or to a common parent component.

```
<Helmet>
  <title>{props.match.params.date}</title>
</Helmet>
```